# Lottie Animation - Colors not showing on react native app

Tags: react-native, lottie

I have added a Lottie loading animation in my React native app, the animation is working so far but somehow colors are not showing but a white animation only.

Here is the code.

```js
<View style={styles.lottieLoadingWrapper}>
  <LottieView
    style={styles.lottieLoading}
    source={require('../assets/loading-2.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
  />
</View>
```

I have not done anything in the stylesheet. I have tried multiple animations but all are simple white.
What could be the mistake I am making here?

Update: Following is the style code

```css
lottieLoadingWrapper: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  alignSelf: 'center',
},
lottieLoading:{
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.66)',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Following is the animation I am using

[Lottie Animation Link](https://lottiefiles.com/6512-love-colorfully-by-amin-edalatipour)

Comment: kindly show style and share your lottie file as well

Comment: Sure, please check I have updated it in question.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View style={styles.lottieLoadingWrapper}>
  <LottieView
    style={styles.lottieLoading}
    source={require('../assets/loading-2.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
  />
</View> 


Please Change the Color in JSON file, Find "sc":"#ffffff" and 
Replace with your color
```